# substitute string within a range

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have text file such as

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A7
A27
A31
A56
A100
A8
A11
```

and I want output like this where A1 to A30 shoud be sustituted with A1 and A31 to A100 should be substituted with A2, using sed, awk or for loop

```
A1
A1
A1
A1
A1
A1
A2
A2
A2
A1
A1
```

I am new to it Kindly help, Thanks and regards

I tried this one

```
sed -i "s/(A1:A10)/A1/g" file.txt
```

I tried with loop also
Kindly improve my coding

```
for i in file.txt; 
  do cat "$i";
     if ((A*>A10)); 
         then
         sed -e 's/A*/A1;
     else sed -e 's/A*/A2;
     fi
 done
```

Comment: I tried a lot but didnt reached there

Comment: So, what happens when you try to run that second one, the `for` loop? How did you end up with that particular code?

Comment: This is almost identical to your previous 2 questions and easily implemented by a tweak to [the awk answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739436/133219) you got to your first question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello [umar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/564967/umar) You can try with this one-line command (it works on Bash and Zsh ) let me explain myself: I iterate over the file output but I trim just the numbers (since all entries start with 'A') and then, I filter each line by an if-elif block where if it's in the range between 1 and 30 then echo "A1" but if it's between 31 and 100 echo "A2", as you requested in the question but all these in one line.

```
for i in `cat text_file |cut -d 'A' -f 2`; do if (($i > 0 && $i <= 30)); then echo 'A1'; elif (($i > 30 && $i <= 100)); then echo 'A2';  fi ; done
```

Please check it and confirm if it works, I'm new answering as well.
Regards.

Comment: Thank you its working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I explained myselft more in my answer