# Replace a string in a column of a text file based on matching string listed in another file

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

Following my previous question I have multiple set of file, so I greped on list and wanted to change other file by using grep file.txt for example I am pasting three file here
File 1

```
chr - seq1 NZ_JAHWGH010000010.1 0 60562 green_a4
chr - seq3 NZ_JAHWGH010000012.1 0 466573 green_a4
chr - seq5 NZ_JAHWGH010000013.1 0 125526 green_a4
chr - seq39 NZ_CAJGBF010000006.1 0 211154 green_a4
chr - seq40 NZ_CAJGBF010000007.1 0 199119 green_a4
chr - seq41 NZ_CAJGBF010000008.1 0 190934 green_a4
chr - seq42 NZ_CAJGBF010000009.1 0 178251 green_a4
```

I greped

```
grep "NZ_JAHWGH" file.txt |awk '{print $3}' >file1.txt
grep "NZ_CAJGBF" file.txt |awk '{print $3}' >file2.txt
```

Now I wanted to use this grep file to change in many different file where only information of seq such as seq1 seq2 is provided. so what I want is using file1.txt all matched list should be substitued as seq1 similarly using second greped file file2.txt I want to substitue all matching pattern as seq2

for example file is given here to be changed by using information from previous file

```
seq3 19301 20914 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 16726 18337 fill_color=green_a0
seq5 167934 169650 fill_color=green_a0
seq42 200621 202367 fill_color=red_a0
seq41 160164 161903 fill_color=green_a0
seq40 31356 33104 fill_color=green_a0
```

changed should be as follows

```
seq1 19301 20914 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 16726 18337 fill_color=green_a0
seq1 167934 169650 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 200621 202367 fill_color=red_a0
seq2 160164 161903 fill_color=green_a0
seq2 31356 33104 fill_color=green_a0
```

so far I tried this command

```
for i in f2.txt; do grep -wf f1.txt $i|awk '{$1="seq1";print}'; grep -wf other.txt $i |awk '{$1="seq2";print}'; done
```

2nd is

```
grep -wf f1.txt f2.txt|sed -e 's/seq[0-9]*/seq1/g'
```

Appreciate for your help
Thanks

Comment: Please read [the awk answer you got to your first question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739436/133219) as everything else you've asked about since can be done with trivial tweaks to that answer. You never need `grep` when you're using `awk` by the way - `grep "NZ_JAHWGH" file.txt |awk '{print $3}'` = `awk '/NZ_JAHWGH/{print $3}' file.txt`

Comment: I have got another file where NZ_JAHWGH and NZ_JAHWGH is not mentioned, only seq1 and seq2 ..... like is mentioned, so If I do any changes in first file, I have to changes in all file for processsing my data, kindly try to understand. i ma having huge file, and aditionally four file is extra where no information sich as id NZ_JAHWGH and NZ_JAHWGH  only other information is there such as seq1... so I am trying to change using ID id such as NZ_JAHWGH and then information from here I am trying to change rest all file. Thanks

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear IMHO however it *looks* like you just want to increment the suffix of the `seq` column each time the prefix of the `NZ_` column changes.

Comment: None of that is hard to handle but, more importantly, you're asking new questions that are easily handled by small changes to existing answers and instead of learning from those answers and building on them you're throwing out completely different code segments using anti-patterns, errors that http://shellcheck.net would tell you about, etc. Read [that first awk answer you got](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739436/133219), try to adapt it for your new requirements, and then ask questions about THAT if you run into problems.

Comment: Suppose I have four file, first file is main file, from where I can track my actual DNA sequence, right, NZ_JAHWGH is accession number of different GENOME, similarly NZ_CAJGBF is also acession number of another genome sequence, right, when I run software it gives four different file. only first file have correct information from where I can easily track my about genome, rest other is having only sequence. so I will keep NZ_CAJGBF as seq 1, but in other file seq 1 and seq... is given so using NZ_CAJGBF I cant change, so i am using another information from 1st file that is seq1 seq2 seq3...

Comment: OK I am going to delete this question